# Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in Shiny Web app

Tags: r, shiny, google-visualization, r-plotly, googlevis

I am trying to create an interactive map using Plotly in the Shiny app that allows the user to select the region by box select and lasso select on the map, then it can return a GoogleVis motion chart showing the statistics on the region selected within the Shiny app. However when it comes to the output function of GoogleVis:

```
output$motionChart <- renderGvis({
           selected <- event_data(event = "plotly_selected", source = "countyMap")
           selectedCountyCases <- as.integer(unlist(selected[3]))
           selectedCounties <- subset(totalComfirmed, totalComfirmed$cases %in% selectedCountyCases)
           gvisCasesDataSubset <- subset(gvisCasesData, countyNames %in% c(selectedCounties$countyNames))
           motionChart <- gvisMotionChart(gvisCasesDataSubset, "countyNames", "Date", options=list(width=800, height=400))
        })
```

It gives the error of:

```
Warning: Error in $: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
  96: renderText [/Users/b.w.h/Documents/JHU/Summer 1/COVID-19 Modeling Project/County Polygon Visualization with Shiny/USMapWithCountyPolygon/server.R#114]
  95: func
  82: origRenderFunc
  81: output$brush
   1: runApp
```

This is very strange because when I checked in the console, the data frame that I am trying to subset with "$" is not atomic.

```
is.atomic(totalComfirmed)
[1] FALSE
```

Why would that happen? Here is my full ui and server function:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(plotly)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("Johns Hopkins COVID-19 Modeling Visualization Map"),
    setBackgroundImage(
        src = "https://brand.jhu.edu/assets/uploads/sites/5/2014/06/university.logo_.small_.horizontal.blue_.jpg"
    ),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            radioButtons("countyFill", "Choose the County Map Type", c("Map by total confirmed", "Map by total death"), selected = "Map by total confirmed"),
            checkboxGroupInput("statesInput", "Choose the State(s)", 
                               c("AL", "MO", "AK", "MT", "AZ", "NE", 
                                 "AR", "NV", "CA", "NH", "CO", "NJ", 
                                 "CT", "NM", "DE", "NY", "DC", "NC", 
                                 "FL", "ND", "GA", "OH", "HI", "OK", 
                                 "ID", "OR", "IL", "PA", "IN", "RI", 
                                 "IA", "SC", "KS", "SD", "KY", "TN", 
                                 "LA", "TX", "ME", "UT", "MD", "VT", 
                                 "MA", "VA", "MI", "WA", "MN", "WV", 
                                 "MS", "WI", "WY"),
                               inline = TRUE),                       
            actionButton("submit", "Submit (may take 30s to load)")
        ), 
        
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(type = "tabs", 
                        tabPanel("County Level", plotlyOutput("countyPolygonMap"), 
                                 htmlOutput("motionChart"), 
                                 verbatimTextOutput("brush")), 
                        tabPanel("State Level", leafletOutput("statePolygonMap")),
                        tags$div(
                            tags$p(
                                "JHU.edu Copyright © 2020 by Johns Hopkins University & Medicine. All rights reserved."
                            ),
                            tags$p(
                                tags$a(href="https://it.johnshopkins.edu/policies/privacystatement",
                                       "JHU Information Technology Privacy Statement for Websites and Mobile Applications")
                            )
                        )
            )
        )
    )
)

library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)
library(rgdal)
library(plotly)
library(rjson)
library(dplyr)
library(viridis) 
library(googleVis)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(data.table)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
    statepolygonZip <- download.file("https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip", 
                                     destfile = "cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
    unzip("cb_2018_us_state_500k.zip");
    statePolygonData <- readOGR("cb_2018_us_state_500k.shp", layer = "cb_2018_us_state_500k", 
                                GDAL1_integer64_policy = TRUE);
    ## obtaning the state shape file data provided by cencus.gov 
    ## for more categories of region shape file: 
    ## https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html
    
    url <- 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json'
    countyGeo <- rjson::fromJSON(file=url)
    ## Obtaining the geographical file for all U.S. counties
    
    url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv"
    covidCases <- read.csv(url2, header = TRUE)
    fips <- sprintf("%05d",covidCases$FIPS)
    colnames(covidCases)[6] <- "countyNames"
    totalComfirmed <- covidCases[,ncol(covidCases)]
    names(totalComfirmed) <- c("countyNames", "cases")
    
    destroyX = function(es) {
        f = es
        for (col in c(1:ncol(f))){ #for each column in dataframe
            if (startsWith(colnames(f)[col], "X") == TRUE)  { #if starts with 'X' ..
                colnames(f)[col] <- substr(colnames(f)[col], 2, 100) #get rid of it
            }
        }
        assign(deparse(substitute(es)), f, inherits = TRUE) #assign corrected data to original name
    }
    destroyX(covidCases)
    
    gvisCasesData <- cbind.data.frame(covidCases$countyNames, covidCases[11,ncol(covidCases)])
    gvisCasesData <- melt(data = setDT(covidCases), id.vars = "countyNames",measure.vars = c(colnames(covidCases)[c(12:ncol(covidCases))]))
    colnames(gvisCasesData)[2:3] <- c("Date", "numCases")
    gvisCasesData$Date <- mdy(gvisCasesData$Date)
    
    
    url3 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_deaths_US.csv"
    covidDeath <- read.csv(url3, header = TRUE)
    colnames(covidDeath)[6] <- "countyNames"
    totalDeath <- covidDeath[,ncol(covidDeath)]
    
    v <- reactiveValues(data = totalComfirmed)
    observeEvent(input$countyFill, {
        if (input$countyFill == "Map by total confirmed") {
            v$data <-  totalComfirmed;
            v$zmin = 100;
            v$zmax = 12000;
            v$hover <- with(covidCases, paste(countyNames));
        }
        if (input$countyFill == "Map by total death") {
            v$data <-  totalDeath;
            v$zmin = 0;
            v$zmax = 1600;
            v$hover <- with(covidDeath, paste(countyNames));
        }
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$submit, {
        req(input$submit)
        
        output$countyPolygonMap <- renderPlotly({
            countyPolygonMap <- plot_ly(source = "countyMap") %>% add_trace(
                countyName <- covidCases$countyNames,
                type="choroplethmapbox",
                geojson=countyGeo,
                locations=fips,
                z=v$data,
                colorscale="Viridis",
                zmin= v$zmin,
                zmax= v$zmax,
                text = ~v$hover,
                marker=list(line=list(width=0),opacity=0.5)
            ) %>% layout(
                mapbox=list(
                    style="carto-positron",
                    zoom =2,
                    center=list(lon= -95.71, lat=37.09))
              %>% event_register(event = "plotly_selected")
            );
            countyPolygonMap;
            ## generating the interactive plotly map
        })
        
        output$motionChart <- renderGvis({
           selected <- event_data(event = "plotly_selected", source = "countyMap")
           selectedCountyCases <- as.integer(unlist(selected[3]))
           selectedCounties <- subset(totalComfirmed, totalComfirmed$cases %in% selectedCountyCases)
           gvisCasesDataSubset <- subset(gvisCasesData, countyNames %in% c(selectedCounties$countyNames))
           motionChart <- gvisMotionChart(gvisCasesDataSubset, "countyNames", "Date", options=list(width=800, height=400))
        })
        
        #output$brush <- renderText({
        #    selected <- event_data(event = "plotly_selected", source = "countyMap")
        #    selectedCountyCases <- as.integer(unlist(selected[3]))
        #    brush <- selectedCounties
        #})

        
        output$statePolygonMap <-renderLeaflet ({
            statesAbbr <- subset(statePolygonData, input$statesInput %in% statePolygonData$STUSPS);
            ## subsetting the shape file with the selected states
            
            leaflet(statesAbbr) %>%
                addPolygons(color = "#444444", weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,
                            opacity = 1.0, fillOpacity = 0.5,
                            fillColor = ~colorQuantile("YlOrRd", ALAND)(ALAND),
                            highlightOptions = highlightOptions
                            (color = "white", weight = 2,bringToFront = TRUE))
        })
        ## producing the map with polygon boundary on the state level
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run

```
url2<- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_US.csv"
covidCases <- read.csv(url2, header = TRUE)
fips <- sprintf("%05d",covidCases$FIPS)
colnames(covidCases)[6] <- "countyNames"
totalComfirmed <- covidCases[,ncol(covidCases)]
names(totalComfirmed) <- c("countyNames", "cases")
```

and then try `is.atomic`, i get

```
is.atomic(totalComfirmed)
# [1] TRUE
```

You've extracted a single column out of a data.frame which by default returns just an atomic vector. Then when you try to do

```
totalComfirmed$cases %in% selectedCountyCases
```

You'll get an error because `totalComfirmed` doesn't have any columns. Perhaps you meant

```
totalComfirmed <- covidCases[,c(which(names(covidCases)=="countyNames"), ncol(covidCases))]
```

Also is `totalComfirmed` a typo? Should it be `totalConfirmed`?